# ¿Cómo seleccionar los registros con la fecha más reciente?

Tags: sql, date

No sé cómo hacer la siguiente consulta, a ver si me podéis ayudar. Tengo la siguiente tabla, en la que hay 2 productos diferentes, insertados en diferentes fechas y horas, y con cantidades diferentes:

- Producto1    1/12/17 15:30 5u
- Producto1    5/12/17 16:00 3u
- Producto1    5/12/17 12:12 1u
- Producto2    1/12/17 15:05 8u
- Producto2    6/12/17 11:45 7u

Y quiero que me devuelva de cada producto el registro con fecha y hora más reciente, pero que no se repita el producto. Así:

- Producto1    5/12/17 16:00 3u
- Producto2    6/12/17 11:45 7u

Cómo lo hago? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando algun RDBMS concreto? ¿Oracle? ¿MySQL? etc.

Comment: Sí, MySQL. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo (ya que no está la información en la pregunta) que la tabla se llama `Tabla`, una posible solución es:

```
select *
from Tabla as T1
where not exists (
  select *
  from Tabla as T2
  where T1.Producto = T2.Producto and T1.Fecha < T2.Fecha)
```

Comment: Pese a que ambas respuestas (la tuya como la de David Isla) son correctas, tengo que aclarar que la clausula EXISTS es mas optimizada que cualquier JOIN, ademas la lógica aplicada a la sub-consulta es, en lo personal, exquisita en su simpleza.

Answer (score 1):

Esta primera consulta te daría la fecha mayor de cada producto:

```
SELECT Producto,
       max(Fecha) max_fecha
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY Producto
```

Obteniendo esto, puedes volver a consultar la tabla Tabla para sacar el resto de información que necesites. Te pongo la sentencia completa:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Producto,
                  max(Fecha) max_fecha
           FROM Tabla
           GROUP BY Producto) maximo on maximo.producto=t.Producto and
                                        maximo.max_fecha=t.Fecha;
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciono así

```
SELECT *
FROM  BSA_TAB_CERTIFICADO_PACIENTE T1
WHERE
    (T1.FECHA_EMITE_CERTIFICADO = 
        (SELECT MAX(FECHA_EMITE_CERTIFICADO)
                FROM BSA_TAB_CERTIFICADO_PACIENTE
                WHERE NUMERO_HISTORIA = :P27_HISTORIA 
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

El error de la primera consulta que es que en lugar de poner LEFT JOIN se debe cambiar por un INNER JOIN para que cruce directamente con lo que encontró en la `MAX(fecha)` y solo de 1 registro

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Producto,
                  max(Fecha) max_fecha
           FROM Tabla
           GROUP BY Producto) maximo on maximo.producto=t.Producto and
                                        maximo.max_fecha=t.Fecha;
```

Lo que se buscaba era sacar el registro con la maxima fecha, con LEFT salen todos y no el de la maxima fecha.

Comment: ¿A que error te refieres si OP no puso código en su pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

> Comparto mi aporte el cual me funcionó, tome como idea las sugerencias anteriores y decidí utilizar tablas temporales.

Contexto:

Necesitaba sacar la cantidad de la fecha más reciente de compra tablas: *facturase* (donde estaba la *fechafactura*) y *facturasedetalle* (código de producto y cantidad)

```sql
#SELECCIONO LA DATA QUE ME INTERESA DE FORMA GENERAL CON RANGO DE FECHAS
drop temporary table if exists ver1;
create temporary table ver1(
        select d.upc, f.fechafactura, d.cantidad
        from facturase as f inner join facturasedetalle as d 
        on f.id=d.idfacturase  
        where fechafactura between 20220801 and 20220819 
        and  d.upc=2510041000000 
        group by  fechafactura, d.upc 
        );

#SELECCIONO LA FECHA MAS RECIENTE DEL LISTADO
drop temporary table if exists ver2;
create temporary table ver2(
       select d.upc, max(distinct(fechafactura)) as fechafactura 
       from facturase as f inner join facturasedetalle as d 
       on f.id=d.idfacturase  
       where fechafactura between 20220801 and 20220819 
       and  d.upc=2510041000000 
       group by d.upc 
       );

#CON EL INNER JOIN SELECCIONO EL LA CANTIDAD DE LA FECHA MAS RECIENTE :)
drop temporary table if exists ver3;
create temporary table ver3(
       select v1.*
       from ver1 as v1 inner join ver2 as v2
       on  v1.upc=v2.upc and v1.fechafactura=v2.fechafactura);

select * from ver3;
```

Answer (score 0):

ordenando las fechas también podría ser:

```sql
select * from(
 select producto,
        fecha,
        cantidad,
        row_number()over(partition by producto order by fecha desc) orden
  from Tabla
)t where t.orden = 1
```